# WPF Localization using an static method

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I have a C# .Net 4.5 WPF application.
The application have to be localizable. Which means I have to be able to change the labels/titles/button/text of everything visual in my application.

I have an existing model to take an id-String and return the text for the given language. Something like:

```
String localizedCancelText = Localize.Text("@Cancel"); //Cancel
String localizedMoneyLeftText = Localize.Text("@MoneyLeft",10); //$10 left
```

Where the Localize.Text(..) method is static.

This works all nicely.

The problem is with the labels/titles, thoses are set in WPF.
The idea is to have all labels(all visual) containing keywords insteed of english text. For example a WPF cancel button would be like:

```
<Button Content="@Cancel"/>
```

And then I have to take the "@Cancel" and lookup how cancel is written in the given language/location/department.

My question is:
How can I do this? I can set every label/button/text from codebehind, but that would be a ugly solution. I would much rather set it in WPF as shown above, and then "somehow" transelate the @Cancel using the Localize.Text(..) method to get the actual cancel text for the given language/location/department.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on this:

http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/07/28/wpf-a-markup-extension-that-can-update-its-target/ 
http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/08/23/wpf-markup-extensions-and-templates/

which allows me to use

```
<Button Content="{markUp:Localized Key=@BigButton}">
```

And still be able to change the language at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

We use a software called [Sisulizer](http://www.sisulizer.com/) that can parse the WPF and extract localizable strings. It can do that for all resources for that matter. We simply import all our resources into Sisulizer and the from there we export a csv file with required translations which we give our translators. Sisulizer builds satelite resource Dlls which we then use in our software.

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use resource file `.resx` extension.you have to declare label and value in resx file.